# Return statement in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data through some API and map into my product page. The problem is when I'm writing the return statement inside `useEffect`, output is not showing in my console, but when I comment out the return statement, then I get data in my console. Why is it?

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 const [filter, setFilter] = useState(data);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
 let componentMounted = true;

 useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch("any_url");
      if (componentMounted) {
        setData(await response.clone().json());
        setFilter(await response.json());
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(filter)
      }
    };
    // return () => {
    //   componentMounted = false;
    // }

    getProducts();
  },[]);
```

Comment: FWIW, consider making `componentMounted` a ref (see `useRef` hook). Otherwise, it will be recreated and initialized to `true` in every render.

Answer (score 2):

**Why:**

A `return` statement will end your function directly and return a value. The code after a `return` statement in a function will not be executed.
So in your case when you uncomment your `return` statement in your `useEffect` hook, than the `getProducts()` call will never happen and you don't see your `console.log()` output.

**Solution:**

You should put the `return` statement in your `useEffect` hook at the last line, so that the `getProducts()` call gets executed before the function returns a value.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch("any_url");
      if (componentMounted) {
        setData(await response.clone().json());
        setFilter(await response.json());
        setLoading(false);
        console.log(filter)
      }
    };

    getProducts();

    // move the return statement to the last line of your useEffect hook
    return () => {
       componentMounted = false;
    }
  },[]);
```